# Drop-off in British English?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

As I understand, the term *drop-off* can mean a steep decline in, say, sales; however, an abrupt cliff is not called a *drop-off*. Only in American English is *drop-off* used to describe a cliff's steep gradient. What would the proper British English term be for an all but vertical cliff gradient?

Comment: A "sheer drop" is what I think I would call it.  You are right that we would not use "drop-off" in Britain for this. Apart from your sales example, it is most often used in the sense of a delivery - "Please would you drop-off these samples XYZ Ltd on your way home".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In British and American English, a 'sheer drop' is common if the cliff is vertical or nearly so.

[Sheer (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sheer)